RL FOR DYNAMIC ENVIRONMENTS?
I'm new to the field of reinforcement learning (RL), and I’m working on a deep RL project where the environment is constantly changing. In this setup, the state and action spaces not only change based on the actions taken at each step but also vary due to external factors in the simulation.
Are basic DRL methods and algorithms, like REINFORCE with epsilon-greedy decay for exploration, sufficient to enable the agent to converge in this dynamic environment? Or are there other techniques and literature I should explore for such cases?
Thank you!
